# Controlling access to the USB Pen drives & other external devices in Mac

Tags: macos

How to grant / restrict access to  external devices attached to the Mac? External devices include UB storage devices and CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely disable the USB port:

```
mv /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext /some/where/for/safekeeping
```

and, restart.

Up through 10.5, Apple published security configuration guides for their server software.  This particular advice is from page 82: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Leopard_Security_Config_2nd_Ed.pdf

(The manual says to remove the .kext, but, if you want to access the USB port again someday, it is a good file to keep around.)

Comment: Is it possible to provide access rights to USB storage devices? For Eg: I want to give either 'Read-only' access or completely block USB storage devices.

Consider that i have a configuration tool; wherein i assign read-only access to CD/DVD.
So when user inserts a CD/DVD into Mac; user should not be able to write to that CD/DVD.

Comment: I did a test where I made a new unix group, put one user in that group, and chgrp the .kext, as well as chmod 750 (so, only root and the specified unix group could see it).  When another user inserts the USB memory, an error is displayed.  When the specified user inserts it, the memory is read; but, this only happens after a reboot.  If you log out (from a no-access user, who has attempted to read the USB), and log in (with the accessible user), and reinsert the memory stick, it still won't be read.  Not a perfect solution; but, perhaps a staring place for someone?